# SSH suddenly asking for DSA

Tags: ssh

After allowing an application to install ssh keys on my local machine, I can no longer connect to my Digital Ocean shell. (The app is not related to DO; totally different.) I get a

```
Permission denied (public key)
```

error that, with -vvv, debugs to

```
Trying private key: /Users/macbook/.ssh/id_dsa
no such identity: path/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
```

My keys are rsa. I have no idea why the machine is asking for dsa.

My .ssh/config file (which I have never read until now) has only information about the application I allowed access. Maybe it was overwritten. If this is the case, could you tell me how to rewrite my .ssh/config file?

My keys on my cloud server (accessed through a DO gui shell) and on my machine still match up. The folder permissions are ok. I've been using this for months with no trouble until now.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

This was probably a result of the third party application overwriting my .ssh/config file. Because the writing of this file was always automated for me, I never took any notice of it. If you try:

- regenerating new keys
- appending the new public key to the authorized_keys file on your server on a new line
- writing a new .ssh/config file as so:

-

```
Host 111.11.11.1
  User bob
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/new_file.pem
```

then you might make it. Somehow now I can't get a passphrase to work on the new keys.

Comment: is there anything in your `.ssh` directory? Installation might have erased the existing keys.

Comment: @xlembouras yes the keys I have been using are still there.

Comment: Any chance you upgraded your ssh agent and need to define
`PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss` in the config file on `Host *` ?

Comment: @xlembouras thanks much but no. actually i've generated new keys and appended them to my server's authorized_keys file. i wrote a new config file. it now accepts the connection, but the passphrase is always wrong, even if i don't use any passphrase. (i've done three new keys - always bad passphrase.) some sort of config somewhere got messed up by the app.